Understanding Massey Products on Borromean Rings
In Algebraic Invariants of Links, by Hillman, page 229 states

Let $G = \pi Bo$ be the group of the Borromean rings $Bo$, and let $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$ be the generators of $H^1(G;R)$ which are Kronecker dual to the meridians $\lbrace x_1,x_2,x_3\rbrace$ (i.e., $f_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$). Then all cup products $f_i\smile f_j$ are $0$. The Massey triple product $\langle f_1,f_2,f_3\rangle$ is defined, with $0$ indeterminacy, and is a generator for $H^2(G;R) \cong R$.


I have computed the group $G$ using the Wirtinger presentation:
$$G = \langle x_1,x_2,x_3\mid [[x_1,x_2^{-1}],x_3] = [[x_2,x_3^{-1}],x_1] = [[x_3,x_1^{-1}],x_2] = e\rangle.$$
I understand now that each $f_i\in H^1(G;R)$ is a group homomorphism $f_i:G\to R$ such that
$$f_i(x_j) = \begin{cases}1 & i = j, \\ 0 & i\neq j;\end{cases}$$
and that $f_i\smile f_j(x_k,x_l) = f_i(x_k)\cdot f_j(x_l)$. But then $f_i\smile f_j(x_i,x_j) = f_i(x_i)\cdot f_j(x_j) = 1\cdot 1 = 1 \neq 0$.
What am I missing?
I thought that maybe $f_i\smile f_j$ is a coboundary, that is,
$$d(f)(g_1,g_2) = f(g_2) - f(g_1g_2) + f(g_1),$$
for some map (of sets) $f:G\to R$. But I cannot figure out which $f$ to select, all I know is that it must satisfy the following
We have that $f_i$, and $f_j$ are group homomorphisms from the multiplicative group $G$ to the additive abelian group of the ring $R$ with its addition. This means that if $g_1,g_2\in G$, and
$$g_1 = x_{b_1}^{a_1}\cdots x_{b_m}^{a_m},\quad g_2 = x_{b_{m+1}}^{a_{m+1}}\cdots x_{b_{m+n}}^{a_{m+n}}$$
where each $b_k\in \lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace$ and $a_k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$(f_i \smile f_j)(g_1,g_2) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\cdot \delta_{ib_k}\right)\left(\sum_{l=m+1}^{m+n}a_l\cdot \delta_{jb_l}\right).$$
